# JavaScript: creating an array of text boxes

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I am looking to create a grid of 3x3 text input boxes, relative to an existing square div, using pure JavaScript. Preferably I would like to construct the grid of a single 1D array that cycles through every third box (if not, then an array of an array of input boxes would do - I hope this makes sense). This is what my code looks like at the moment, but only three of the boxes show when I cycle the array length (if I don't then the array extends linearly across beyond the div confines):

```
var row0 = new Array(9);

for (var i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
     {
            row0[i] = document.createElement('input');
            row0[i].style.position = "absolute";
            row0[i].type = "text";  
            row0[i].style.marginLeft = 35px *i % 105  + "px";
            row0[i].style.width = "35px";
            row0[i].style.height = "35px";
            document.getElementById('block1').appendChild(row0[i]);      
     }
```

How can I get the grid to display correctly?

Comment: You may want to use classes here

Comment: why don't you just create a `<table>` of textboxes ?

Comment: All of your 9 elements are being generated, but they're being stacked on top of each other. You need to apply the margin-left type logic to position the blocks vertically. Something like a margin-top of 0, 35, and 70 depending on the value of `i`.

Comment: I did try to use marginTop with 'i' but it creates a diagonal distribution as i changes with each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a combination of javascript and CSS

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/x8dSP/3010/

JS

```
window.onload = function () {
    var parent_div = document.createElement("div")
    parent_div.id = "parent"
    document.body.appendChild(parent_div);

    var x = 0;
    while (x < 9) {
        var child_input = document.createElement("input")
        child_input.className = "child"
        document.getElementById(parent_div.id).appendChild(child_input);
        x++;
    }
}
```

CSS

```
div {
    width: 150px;
}
input {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 5px;
}
```